# XML response from the server idhttp

Tags: xml, delphi, networking, idhttp

Get send request to the server and receives an error 409, the program is suspended, using try except and ignore her, I had also an error 409 and XML response, how do I read it?

HTTP.Response.gettext - not give it to me, only the information about the server

http.response.rawheaders.commatext - only the information about the server

content lenght matches

The answer can be seen in the sniffer

I get an answer in the program?

Comment: Get what answer ? The response content ? How are you getting the content in code ? Have you even tried the code from my (now deleted) post ?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Jetty(6.1.x)
Content-Length: 160
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><error code="10003" appid="1"><failure cause="INVALID_PASSWORD" field="password" value="******"/></error>

Comment: This is in response to the sniffer through http.get I only get

HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Jetty(6.1.x)
Content-Length: 160
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: You can't get it maybe because `failure cause="INVALID_PASSWORD"` ? Anyway, please try avoid to write so many comments; rather include all needed information to the question. Thanks!

Comment: I realise that English is not your first language, and that you are new here. But this is a poor question. It's hard to understand what your problem is. You are adding more detail in the comments, rather than in the question. This is a wiki. You can edit the question with more details. I suggest you delete your comments and transfer them to the question. You need to take more time to clarify the question. If you do that you will get good help.

Answer (score 2):

When `TIdHTTP` receives an HTTP error from the server, like 409, it raises an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception, and the content text of the error will be in its `ErrorMessage` property, eg:

```
try
  IdHTTP1.Get(...);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
  begin
    // HTTP-specific error
    ShowMessage(Format('HTTP Error'#13'Response: %d %s'#13'Content: %s', [E.ErrorCode, E.Message, E.ErrorMessage]));
  end;
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    // any other error
    ShowMessage(Format('Exception'#13'Class: %s'#13'%s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]));
  end;
end;
```

When you encounter the password error, it should show a popup message box saying the following:

```
HTTP Error
Response: 409 Conflict
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><error code="10003" appid="1"><failure cause="INVALID_PASSWORD" field="password" value="******"/></error>
```